# Equivalent probability with independence question $P(A,B,C) = P(A|B)P(B|C)P(C)$

Tags: probability, independence

So, the statement is that:
$$P(A,B,C) = P(A|B)P(B|C)P(C)$$
if ($A$ is independent of $B$ given $C$) and ($A$ is independent of $C$)

Here is how I tried to work it out:
$$P(A,B,C) = P(B)P(A|B)P(C|A,B) \text{ (using the chain rule)}$$
$$P(A,B,C) = P(A|B)P(B,C|A)  \text{ (using the product rule)}$$

But from here I can't seem to go anywhere. I've tried taking other routes as well, but I keep ending up at a dead end. I was trying to find a way to go from $P(B,C|A)$ to $P(B|C)P(C)$. However, this may not be the correct route to take in the first place.

I was wondering if anyone knew where I went wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose **$A$ is independent of $C$ given $B$**. Then
\begin{align}
\textbf{P}(ABC) &= \textbf{P}(AC|B)\textbf{P}(B) = \textbf{P}(A|B)\textbf{P}(C|B)\textbf{P}(B) = \textbf{P}(A|B)\textbf{P}(BC) \\
&= \textbf{P}(A|B)\textbf{P}(B|C)\textbf{P}(C)
\end{align}

But I am not sure whether those two conditions $A$ is independent of $B$ given $C$ and $A$ is independent of $C$ imply $A$ is independent of $C$ given $B$.

Based on given two conditions, what I can do best is
\begin{align}
\textbf{P}(ABC) &= \textbf{P}(AB|C)\textbf{P}(C) = \textbf{P}(A|C)\textbf{P}(B|C)\textbf{P}(C) = \textbf{P}(A)\textbf{P}(B|C)\textbf{P}(C)
\end{align}

Trace back to see under what condition the equality holds. We have to have
\begin{align}
\textbf{P}(AB|C) = \textbf{P}(A|B)\textbf{P}(B|C)
\end{align}
which is equivalent to say
\begin{align}
\frac{\textbf{P}(ABC)}{\textbf{P}(C)} = \frac{\textbf{P}(AB)}{\textbf{P}(B)}\frac{\textbf{P}(BC)}{\textbf{P}(C)}
\end{align}
and by multiplying $\textbf{P}(C)$, 
\begin{align}
\frac{\textbf{P}(AB)\textbf{P}(BC)}{\textbf{P}(B)} = \textbf{P}(ABC).
\end{align}
Hence any condition satisfies the above equality will be suffice.

Comment: Oh I see, I think you're absolutely right.

I believe A being independent of C would mean that it is independent of C regardless of the evidence. ( So whether B is a observed or not)

I think the top solution you posted is definitely the way to solve it. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Backwardsman I am glad my answer helps :)

Comment: @induction601 "But I am not sure whether those two conditions $A$ is independent of $B$ given $
C$ and $A$ is independent of $C$ imply $A$ is independent of $C$ given $B$."  $~$ [Why, yes indeed; they do](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_independence#Rules_of_conditional_independence). $$\begin{split}A \perp B \mid C \text{ and } A\perp C &~\implies~ A \perp B, C \\ A \perp B, C  &~\implies~ A \perp C\mid B\end{split} $$

Comment: @Backwardsman " I believe A being independent of C would mean that it is independent of C regardless of the evidence. " Well, no; $A\perp C$ *on its own* does not infer $A\perp C\mid B$.  Classic counter example: Toss two fair coins and let $A$ be the event the left coin shows heads, $C$ be the event the right coin does, and $B$ be the event that the coins show the same result .

Comment: @GrahamKemp Wow, thank you so much for pointing out this reference. My intuition says it is true but I wasn't sure how to prove it. :)

Comment: @GrahamKemp Oh I see. Thanks for the correction. The example was great too!